# jenkins helm chart deploy not retaning saved or passed settings

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed jenkins via helm chart and am using persistence with existing claim. The pod comes up and app is available however when I configure LDAP then restart the pod I loose my settings.

Ive tried several persistence settings in values.yaml w/o any luck. Any suggestions?

Default values.yaml:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/jenkins/values.yaml

Here's the ldap settings in my values.yaml: using generic values of course.

```
controller:
JCasC:
configScripts:
ldap-settings: |
jenkins:
securityRealm:
ldap:
configurations:
- server: ldap.acme.com
rootDN: dc=acme,dc=uk
managerPasswordSecret: ${LDAP_PASSWORD}
groupMembershipStrategy:
fromUserRecord:
attributeName: "memberOf"
```

I can see the values I passed when I run the following command:

helm -n jenkins get values jenkins

The values in ldap-settings look correct however they are not reflected in the UI. Is there something im missing?

Comment: Any error log in Jenkins pod?

Comment: there are no relevant errors.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and i changed the following settings :

```
jcasc:
  defaultConfig: false
```

I answered here :

[Jenkins doesn't keep data when I upgrade Jenkins config using helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77314730/jenkins-doesnt-keep-data-when-i-upgrade-jenkins-config-using-helm/77347042#77347042)