# Jenkins doesn't keep data when I upgrade Jenkins config using helm

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-helm

chart: jenkinsci/jenkins

chart version: 4.7.2

When I upgrade Jenkins config using Helm, Jenkins `HOME_DIR` can't keep data. Also I change admin password and upgrade Jenkins config, It can't keep it. What should I do?

Upgrade command

```
helm upgrade -n jenkins jenkins -f values.yaml ./jenkins
```

This is my values.yaml

```
controller:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
.
.
.
persistence:
  enabled: true
```

pv

```
pvc-7b6427dd-37b9-47bb-9e4b-05451218e210   8Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    jenkins/jenkins                                gp2                     85m
```

pvc

```
jenkins   Bound    pvc-7b6427dd-37b9-47bb-9e4b-05451218e210   8Gi        RWO            gp2            85m
```

Comment: Did you create a PVC for to be used with your chart ? Just settings persistence to true don't mean that the data will be maintained cf [Jenskins](https://github.com/CenterForOpenScience/helm-charts/blob/master/jenkins/README.md#persistence-values)

Comment: pvc has bound at jenkins pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep i got the same problem i just desactivate JCasC inside the values.yaml

```
  JCasC:
    defaultConfig: false
```

helm upgrade jenkins jenkins/jenkins -f values.yml --install